# What happens to the state of a react component when the component is re-rendered?

Tags: reactjs, state

What happens to the state of a react component when the component is re-rendered?

Does it remain unaffected, or does it get reset to some 'default' value? Why?

Comment: rendering depend on state and props. so state remains unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh the page, components get re-rendered and state get's reset to default value  is it because when component re-rendered we have following lifecycle of react that runs

1. Initialization here react constructor() run and set the state to default value
2. Mounting

   componentWillMount() , componentDidMount()
3. Updation

   componentWillRecieveProps(), shouldComponentUpdate(), componentWillUpdate(),componentDidUpdate()
4. Unmounting - This run when you are leaving the component

   componentWillUnmount()

Comment: when you refresh the page, that is a different type of re-rendering, I guess. My question was also about when the props of a component change

Answer (score 0):

- The state does not depend on the rendering of a component and remains unaffected by re-rendering.
- The state gets updated only by a lifecycle method or by a call to setState.

Answer (score 0):

Change in the state will re-render with an updated state.

A state can be changed either by user interaction or a life cycle method only.

When a state is changed, only the updated part will be rendered